# Implicit base conversions not occuring when passing Python objects to functions

Tags: python, c++, c++11, boost, boost-python

I've hit a nasty snag in my Boost.Python adventure.

I'm trying to pass a derived class, `GuiState`, into a function that takes a `shared_ptr` to it's parent class, `State`.

I assumed that some sort of automatic conversion would have taken place, but I'm mistaken apparently!

This is the Boost.Python class defintion for `State`:

```
    class_<state_t, std::shared_ptr<state_t>, noncopyable>("State", init<>());
```

And `GuiState`:

```
    class_<gui_state_t, bases<state_t>, std::shared_ptr<gui_state_t>, noncopyable>("GuiState", init<>());
```

And `StateMgr`:

```
    class_<state_mgr_t, noncopyable>("StateMgr", no_init)
        .def("push", &state_mgr_t::push);
```

`state_mgr_t::push`'s function signature is thus:

```
void push(const std::shared_ptr<state_t>& state, unsigned char link_flags);
```

I can then run the following script:

```
from mandala import *

states.push(State(), STATE_FLAG_ALL) #runs fine
states.push(GuiState(), STATE_FLAG_ALL) #error below
```

The last line generates the following error:

```
Python argument types in
    StateMgr.push(StateMgr, GuiState, int)
did not match C++ signature:
    push(struct mandala::state_mgr_t {lvalue}, class std::shared_ptr<struct mandala::state_t>, unsigned char)
```

I've done a bunch of searching for automatic type conversions and such but to no avail. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What if you changed `std::shared_ptr<gui_state_t>` in the class declaration of `GuiState` to `std::shared_ptr<state_t>`?

Comment: @HuuNguyen That doesn't work, it throws a compile error: `error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'mandala::state_t *' to 'mandala::gui_state_t *'`

Comment: @csbasnett, ah, worth a shot. This might be an actual bug in boost python, I don't see anything that could be wrong with your setup. Have you looked at the open tickets on the project website?

Comment: `shared_ptr<>` constructor from raw pointer is marked `explicit`, and there is no assignment from a raw pointer. You really need a `shared_ptr` instance here.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov Nowhere here am I assigning from a raw pointer.

Comment: First of all, this is no where near a *minimal* example. Second of all, [can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ecd7ae259f98cde).

Comment: @Barry The problem doesn't seem to occur when using boost::shared_ptr, only when using std::shared_ptr to wrap the objects. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/055a2988d16c2dda

Comment: regardless of ability to reproduce, can you please remove all the irrelevant stuff from your question?  `change_link_flags` is not called, and eliminating it won't make the bug go away, right?  So it is irrelevant.  Repeatedly do this (eliminating stuff that is not required) and your question has a lot less noise.  Once you get rid of every method, see the minimum class requirements are and function requirements are.  *minimal examples* are gold.

Comment: It looks like this is related to an open [bug](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6545) (Warning, the boost svn site has an expired certificate).

Comment: @HuuNguyen This is upsetting. Time to convert everything to `boost::shared_ptr` I guess. :(

Comment: @cmbasnett, yeah it looks like you have to make some implementation of this [file](https://github.com/boostorg/python/blob/3e405b6fd5db5615bbef241763de070118222ca7/include/boost/python/converter/shared_ptr_to_python.hpp) that uses `std::shared_ptr` instead of `boost::shared_ptr`. I'll stop here since SO isn't a ticket tracker, but you get idea.